# How to create a query to get some products related with the identified user?

Tags: users, database

I want make a query for get some products related with the identified user. The type contain has a taxonomy field called 'operating system' and the main profile has also it. For example: If a user has a 'Android Phone' he has to see all products that have this operating system.

Anyone know how can I do it?

I have tried with many modules and I'm looking in the database now.

Comment: You can use _views_ module for the same.

Comment: What is a Poducts entity? it is a node or DrupalCommerce Product or something else?